# Get values from MySQL by arrays without loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm trying to get value from Database on Website by two arrays. I don't really know how to do that, and can't find some good answers to my question.

So, I want to make a multilingual webpage with 3 languages. I created a database with the columns `wordid`, `word`, `en`, `de`, `ru`, and I want to get a value by word in one of the languages.

This is my table:

```
WORDID     WORD          EN      DE      RU
1          admin_hello   Hello  Hallo  Privet
```

I want get a value with something like $lang['admin_hello']['de'], without a loop.

PHP:

```
$translation = "SELECT word_id, word, en, ru, lt FROM translation";
$translation_result = mysql_query($translation);

if ($translation_result) {
    while ($lang = mysql_fetch_assoc($translation_result)) {

    echo $lang['admin_hello']['en'];
    echo $lang['admin_hello']['de'];
    echo $lang['admin_hello']['ru'];
    }
}
```

Yes, it uses while, but it is not working. How can I get a value with something like `$lang['admin_hello']['en']` without a loop, because for every row, it prints a value, so I would like to have it without a loop, to translate a whole page.

Any idea, how I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get this out of the way quickly: you should stop using the mysql_* functions immediately, and use mysqli or PDO instead. The mysql_* functions have been completely removed in PHP 7. Secondly, this sort of thing can't be done without a loop. PHP can only map a MySQL row to a single dimension array. You can probably dig up a library for pivot tables or something, but you may as well just write something this simple yourself.

With that said, your code doesn't appear to do what you want. The `admin_hello` array key would have to correspond to an `admin_hello` column, which you are not selecting.

If you're trying to map your entire `translation` table to an array that has the `word` (or `word_id`) as the first key, and the language (en/de/ru) as the second key, you can buld the array within a loop. I'll keep your mysql_* functions as-is so that it's easier to see what is happening, but *please* make the effort to refactor your code for mysqli or PDO.

```
// Load the words
$words = array();
$language_whitelist = array('en', 'de', 'ru')
$translation = "SELECT word_id, word, en, ru, de FROM translation";
$translation_result = mysql_query($translation);

if (mysql_num_rows($translation_result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($translation_result)) {
        foreach ($language_whitelist as $language) {
            $words[$row['word_id']][$language] = $row[$language];
        }
    }
}

// Display all the words as a demo
foreach ($words AS $word) {
    print_r($word);
}

// Or, get a specific word
print $words['admin_hello']['ru'];
```

Alternatively, if you only want to call a word on-demand, you could write it directly into a query. Here is an example function you might use. Again, I'm using the obsolete and insecure mysql_* functions to keep things understandable. DO NOT use this code as-is. Use a prepared statement to sanitize your query against SQL injections (imagine if you were trying to translate the word "you're", for example).

```
function translate ($word, $language)
{
    $sql = "SELECT {$language} FROM translation WHERE word='{$word}'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row[0];
    }
    else { 
        // Return the original word if no result is found
        return $word;
    }
}

// And a demo (assuming you have a translation for "Hello World"):
print "This is how you say 'Hello World' in Russian: " . translate("Hello World", "ru");
```

Comment: Thank you, for your time and helpful information about secuirty against SQL injection, and of course answer to my question. Works fine, so i'm going learn about the PDO ar mysqli.